# crash with lid closure

Tags: suspend, laptop, asus, crash

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and whenever I close the lid the applications symbols become terminals, the background goes blue, and clicking on anything causes a secondary desktop to pop up with nothing in it and nothing works. If you click on an application it just crashes. I have tried to change the grub settings, replace the screensaver settings with light window, and a few other things. Until I close the laptop everything works fine though.

Comment: Please edit the question and add more details about the model of your laptop. Do you have a dedicated graphics card?